# How to make template constructor argument deductible?

Tags: templates, c++17

My default ctor:

```
Pool(   void *const pStart,
        const size_t size,
        gen::Delegate<void, void*const> deallocator = gen::Delegate<void, void*const>::Build<&gen::NoOp>()) noexcept{...}
```

I want to have also this ctor (c++17, ctor delegating and class template argument deduction):

```
template<class Allocator>
        Pool(Allocator & allocator, const size_t amount)
            :
            Pool(
                allocator.Allocate(TotalSizeRequired(amount), AlignOfBlock()),
                TotalSizeRequired(amount),
                gen::Delegate<void, void*const>::Build<Allocator, &Allocator::Deallocate>(&allocator))
        {}
```

Shouldnt this work? I keep getting left of .Allocate must be a class (error C2228 on VS)

Comment: My guess is, you are doing something like `char buf[size]; Pool pool(buf, size);` and for this call, the templated constructor is a better match than the non-templated one. You need to use SFINAE techniques to make the second constructor ineligible when the first argument is not in fact of a class type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Spot on.. And 'explicit' doesnt seem to work, void * seems to make explicit useless